# Changing the colour of a wxTextCtrl when Enabled=False

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Is there a way to change the colour of a wxTextCtrl when it is disabled or another way to lock the control for input when it is enabled?

I don't like the gray text on a gray background, with a gray border, it makes the information inside the control harder to read.

I'm using wxSmith, there is no tag available for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also give the wxtextCtrl the style **wxTE_READONLY** at creation time to do the same thing.

Regards
Xav'

Comment: Both options work fine but this one is less work, that's important for a lazy person like me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Call `SetEditable(false)` for the text control to block input.

Comment: Excellent solution,  I'm unable to change the values and I can still select and copy the values. THANK YOU!!